# IDA does not break on new threads entry points, OllyDBG does

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida, ollydbg

I am debugging a program with IDA Pro 6.4

The debugged program creates multiple threads for different purpose. I do not know what is the start address of the content I want to debug. Therefore I used OllyDBG to break everytime a new thread is created.
It works really well, and OllyDBG breaks on the newly created thread entry point.

I now try to do the same technique with IDA, I could use the start address I got by using OllyDBG but let's try not to cheat.
I am trying to break on each thread creation.
The debugger options I activated are "suspend on process entry point" and "suspend on thread start/exit"

[image: IDA options]

I can see in the threads being created in the tool logging bar, but IDA won't break.
Am I missing anything? How could I reproduce OllyDBG behaviour using IDA?

Comment: It seems like you can step only through one thread at any given point of time. So you should set breakpoint at thread start address and resume the execution before `CreateThread` call is made. The option "suspend on thread start/exit" is thus can reproduce the same behavior without the need to set breakpoint manually.